# Redis funciona en local pero en produccion no. Node js

Tags: nodejs, express, redis

Tengo el siguiente controller:

```
import { productosdb } from '../models/productos.models.js'
import slug from 'slug';
import { createClient } from 'redis';


let client = createClient({
    socket:{
        host: process.env.REDIS_URI || '127.0.0.1'
    }
});

(async () => {
    await client.connect();
})();


const traeTodosLosProductos = async (req,res,next) => {
    try {
        //Buscamos info en redis
        const reply = await client.get('productos');

        //si existe info, terminamos response devolviendo la info
        if(reply) return res.status(200).send(JSON.parse(reply));

        //si llegamos hasta aca, no esta en redis, hacemos la consulta a la base de datos y registramos en caché.
        productosdb.findAll({
            attributes: { exclude: ['id'] }
        }).then(async produc => {
            res.status(200).json(produc);
            await client.set(
                'productos',
                JSON.stringify(produc),
                {
                    EX: 10,
                }
            );
        })   
    } catch (error) {
        return next(error)
    }
}
```

Que en local, funciona de 10. La primer consulta demora 500 ms y la segunda 3:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esta en produccion:

**https://ecommerce-2xh0.onrender.com/api/v1/productos**

Nunca recibo una respuesta, y despues de un largo tiempo recibo el error: **request timeout**

Los demas EndPoints funcionan correctamente (obviamente no aplico redis, redis solamente aplico en el endpoint que no funciona)

**https://ecommerce-2xh0.onrender.com/api/v1/productos/2**

El proyecto esta correctamente funcionando en render.com

No recibo mas errores, en la console de render.com tengo lo siguiente:

```
Nov 1 09:09:45 AM  [2/4] Fetching packages...
Nov 1 09:09:52 AM  info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
Nov 1 09:09:52 AM  info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
Nov 1 09:09:52 AM  [3/4] Linking dependencies...
Nov 1 09:09:52 AM  warning Workspaces can only be enabled in private projects.
Nov 1 09:09:55 AM  [4/4] Building fresh packages...
Nov 1 09:09:55 AM  success Saved lockfile.
Nov 1 09:09:55 AM  Done in 16.69s.
Nov 1 09:09:55 AM  ==> Generating container image from build. This may take a few minutes...
Nov 1 09:11:12 AM  ==> Uploading build...
Nov 1 09:11:53 AM  ==> Starting service with 'node index.js'
```

No se que puede ser....

EDIT:

Pareciera que se traba cuando hago el **client.get**
Por consola, podemos ver los tiempo de rtas de los endpoints:

```
Nov 1 11:36:58 AM  GET /api/v1/productos/2 200 183 - 97.461 ms
Nov 1 11:37:02 AM  GET /api/v1/productos - - - - ms
Nov 1 11:37:07 AM  GET /api/v1/productos - - - - ms
```

EDIT 2:

Agregue las siguintes lineas de codigo:

```
client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Conectado a Redis Server');
});

client.on('error', (err)=>{
    console.error(err.message)
});
```

y , evidentemente, tengo algo mal en la configuracion de createClient.

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND red-xxxxxxxxxxx:6379
```

Comment: fijate la url/uri si sigue la nomenclatura correcta. el comentario/respuesta de @JHwang refiere a que [getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND](https://github.com/nodejs/node/search?q=getaddrinfo+ENOTFOUND) indicaría un [error de dns](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dnslookuphostname-options-callback) sucede a veces cuando al usar dominios o subdominios la maquina donde corre el código no sabe su nombre

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Trabajo en el equipo de ingeniería de Render. No sé cuál es el valor de `REDIS_URI`, pero parece que pudiera estar en el formato de cadena de conexión completa (ejemplo: `redis://host:port`).

En ese caso, deberás conectarte de este modo:

```
createClient({
  url: process.env.REDIS_URI || 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
});
```

Comment: REDIS_URI esta bien configurada ya que sino me largaria un error al intentar conectarse. El problema esta en el GET. MAs especificamente en ** const reply = await client.get('productos'); **

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Debes traducir tu respuesta.

Comment: @gisela por tu comentario parece que esta respuesta no solucionó el problema, sino que es otra cosa. Entonces, ¿por qué la marcaste como aceptada?